# Allow Specific URL patterns to bypass Spring Security Login

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have a web application protected by spring security. However, there is one particular URL pattern that I do not want to apply any security to. I've tried a few different approaches, but none of them seem to be working. Whenever I attempt to go to that specific URL, I am forwarded to the `spring_security_login` page.

A piece of the web.xml:

```
<!-- NOT SECURE -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dontSecureServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.com.gov.lol.DontSecure</servlet-class> 
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dontSecureServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/dontSecure</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- SECURE -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>secureServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.com.gov.lol.Secure</servlet-class> 
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>secureServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- SECURITY FILTER -->
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

A piece of the security-context.xml:

```
<!-- This did not work -->
<http pattern="/dontSecure" security="none" />

<http entry-point-ref="entryPoint" use-expressions="true">
    <custom-filter ref="customFilter" position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />

    <!-- I've also tried adding the following here (with no luck) -->
    <intercept-url pattern="/dontSecure" filters="none" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/secureMe" requires-channel="https" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/secureUs" requires-channel="https" />

</http>

<!-- I have even tried adding a separate <http> block just for /dontSecure -->
<http>
    <intercept-url pattern="/dontSecure" security="none" />
</http>
```

Again, with any combination of the above configuration, the url `/dontSecure` is still forwarded to the spring login page.

Any ideas as to what could be causing this?

Cheers.

**UPDATE**

From the server logs, it seems that the `/dontSecure` url is loading the `dontSecureServlet`. However, an error seems to be generated and I am being forwareded the 404 error page (which is configured as /404.htm, which must be what brings me back to the login page).

I've included some extra snippits from the web.xml that I didn't think were relevant at first.

Answer (score 2):

Try to change your intercept-url in your configuration with this one:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/dontSecure/**" access="permitAll" />
```

not in a separate `<http>` tag

Comment: Thanks for the answer mseriolo. I removed the other configuration and added your suggestion to the bigger `<http>` block, but I am still getting forwarded to the login page

Comment: I updated my configuration to your suggestion and I am still being forwarded to the login page ]:

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be caused by the fact that your custom filter is getting applied to all the paths. You have to find a way to register your custom filter only for certain paths (I could show you how to do this in Spring Boot, but you probably aren't using it).

Comment: Hi geoand, unfortunetly I am not using spring boot. That is an interesting suggestion though, I will look into it

Comment: @Mac If you are just starting the project it should not be too difficult to switch to boot.

Comment: Sorry to say this is already an existing project in my team. I am just trying to add some extra functionality.